# Dois tipos de cadastros diferentes com firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Opa galera, estou tendo dificuldades para montar um sistema de cadastro com dois tipo de usuarios diferentes, gostaria de estar cadastrando um usuario do tipo adm e um usuario comum,  porem estou exibindo os dados em um fragment com o firebase e para isso preciso passar um child com o parametro de onde ele ira buscar os dados... Mas com os adm ele da erro, erro no qual eu deveria passar o child com o nó de adm para solucionar ... Como fazer para mudar os tipos de usuarios que iriam logar e passar esses parametros para esse child baseado na opçao do usuario, ou entao como fazer para o firebase puxar dados de dois childs diferentes na mesma referencia ???

Comment: Eu acho que não é possível, você teria de fazer duas buscas e combinar os dados de alguma forma, não existe union ou join no firebase.

Comment: Será que nao teria uma maneira de fazer o tratamento desses dados e passar em uma variavel string com o valor do nó ??? O problema seria pegar as opçoes do usuario no login... Ele selecionaria a opçao de login e dps eu teria que passar essa opçao, um valor para para o fragment com a variavel com o child